# Did Yitzhak Kaduri leave a note implying the Jewish Messiah is named Yehoshua?

Tags: religion, judaism

[Yitzhak Kaduri](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Yitzhak_Kaduri) was a renown rabbi who died in 2006.

As explained in the above Wikipedia page, there are claims that he left a note to be opened after his death. The note, when decoded as an acrostic, gives the name Yehoshua, and that is being interpreted as the name of the Mashiach (Jewish Messiah).

[IsraelChai.com](https://www.israelchai.com/rav-kaduri-and-the-messiah/) contains a purported copy of the note, and links the name to Yeshua (and then to Jesus in English).

Did Kaduri leave such a note?

Comment: Seeing as this is a religious question what exactly motivated you to post this question here and not on the whole SE dedicated to this religion?

Comment: Remember skepticism may in some ways be a euphemism for atheism, but this SE is not in the business of being an echo chamber for anti-religious sentiments.

Comment: From Wikipedia, it appears the basis for the claim is a note allegedly written by Kaduri to be opened after his death, with a possibly coded message about the Messiah.  I think the question of whether he wrote the note is on-topic, though we may not be able to make much progress answering it.  But the *meaning* of the note is a matter of religious interpretation and is outside the scope of this site.

Comment: I agree with @NateEldredge. The meaning of the note (Yehoshua) is something the hebrew and christian can duke it out. But did he really write that note in the first place? Is the note real? Why did he write the note? Why he did it in such a way that the note is opened after he died? Why not just write a note when he was still alive?

Comment: @user4951: The first two of those questions are on topic (but they are really the same question).  The last three are not, since they are about [motivations](https://skeptics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/621/politics-beliefs-and-motivations-questions-should-not-be-allowed-here).